# I need to Add a number to every number in an array and reverse it. Figured out the reverse part. output should be 25 24 23 Java

Tags: arrays, addition

int[] list1 = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20};
    int[] list2 = reverse(list1);

```
for(int row=0;row<list1.length;row++){
        System.out.print(list2[row]);
        System.out.println();

}



}

public static int[] reverse(int[] list){
int[] result=new int[list.length];
for(int i=0,j=result.length-1;i<list.length;i++,j--){
    result[j]=list[i];
}
return result;

}
```

Comment: What language is this? Please [edit] your question and add a language tag. See [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number you have to add is same for every element then you can add it on the loop when you are reversing the array.

```
public static int[] reverseAndAdd(int[] list){
int[] result=new int[list.length];
for(int i=0,j=result.length-1;i<list.length;i++,j--){
    result[j]=list[i] + theNumberYouWantToAdd;
}
return result;

}
```

Otherwise You have to run two loops one for adding and the other for reversing the array.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. I figured I had to do something like that, just didn't know where.